# Using PHP to run another PHP script through command line not working

Tags: php, command-line

I have a file located at /tmp/names which holds some random names of people.

When I the following command directly from command line everything works fine:

```
cat /tmp/names | php /scripts/makechange.php -i -r 'Shuffles names and re-orders'
```

However when I run from my php script using:

```
echo "Beginning script...";
echo shell_exec("cat /tmp/names | php /scripts/makechange.php -i -r 'Shuffles names and re-orders'");
echo "Script complete!";
```

It just stays stuck as seen below until I ctrl-c. Any ideas what I am doing wrong? I am using a Mac OS Sierra and iterm2.

[image]

Comment: Can you post a short example of what `makechange.php` is doing?

Comment: is php running in safe mode? http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

Comment: Why not just require the script that you want to execute? Instead of using switches, you could check to see if a $_SESSION variable is set in the script that is being included. As far as why it's not executing, that's hard to say without you actually posting code from makechange.php. Something in that file is causing an infinite loop, otherwise shell_exec would issue a warning/error